# Getting no module named pandas error in airflow even after pandas getting successfully installed

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, kubernetes, airflow

How to resolve the error no module named pandas when one node (in Airflow's DAG) is successful in using it(pandas) and the other is not?

I am unable to deduce as to why I am getting an error no module named pandas.

I have checked via `pip3 freeze` and yes, the desired pandas version does show up.

I have deployed this using docker on a kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BashOperator raising ImportError for a lib used in other PythonOperators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53761948/bashoperator-raising-importerror-for-a-lib-used-in-other-pythonoperators)

Answer (score 1):

[Pandas is generally required](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/setup.py#L292), and sometimes used in some hooks to return dataframes. Well, it's possible that Airflow was installed with `pip` and not `pip3` possibly being added as a Python 2 module and not a Python 3 module (though, using `pip` should have installed Pandas when one looks at the [`setup.py`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/setup.py#L292)).

Which Operator in your DAG is giving this error?
Do you have any PythonVirtualEnvironmentOperators or BashOperators running `python` from the command line (and thus possibly not sharing the same environment that you're checking has `pandas`)?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was running airflow with docker compose with a custom docker image that installed additional packages using `pip install`.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM apache/airflow:slim-2.7.2-python3.11
ADD airflow/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```yaml
services:
  airflow:
    build: .
    environment:
      AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: SequentialExecutor
      AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
      AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
      AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER: /data/dags
      _AIRFLOW_DB_MIGRATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: airflow
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: airflow
      AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__EXPOSE_CONFIG: 'true'
      AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND: airflow.secrets.local_filesystem.LocalFilesystemBackend
      AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND_KWARGS: '{"variables_file_path": "/data/variables.yml", "connections_file_path": "/data/connections.yml"}'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '8793:8793'
      - '8794:8794'
    volumes:
      - ./airflow:/data
    command: 'standalone'
```

I was originally getting the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'` error at DAG import time. That error went away when I installed the pandas package by adding the line `pandas==2.1.1` to the `requirements.txt` file. But then I started getting the same error on the same DAG, but only when executing the DAG. Though on first glance the error looked like the same one as before, on closer look the error was for a different package

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
Exception: pandas library not installed, run: pip install 'apache-airflow-providers-common-sql[pandas]'.
```

The runtime error went away when I installed `apache-airflow-providers-common-sql[pandas]` by adding the line `apache-airflow-providers-common-sql[pandas]==1.7.2` to the requirements.txt. I did have to remove the `pandas==2.1.1` line from the requirements.txt as it looked like when both `apache-airflow-providers-common-sql[pandas]` and `pandas` were specified, there was a version mismatch and hence the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'` error at runtime still persisted.

**Final requirements.txt:**

```
apache-airflow-providers-postgres==5.6.1
apache-airflow-providers-common-sql[pandas]==1.7.2
```