# BashOperator raising ImportError for a lib used in other PythonOperators

Tags: python, airflow

I have a set of tasks in my dag builder module which uses Python operator as used worldwide in Airflow. I am deploying airflow using docker on kubernetes.

A task is failing with the error message: `no module named pandas`. The other tasks using pandas are successful.

Yes, I did enter the container(workers) and found out that `pip3 freeze` does show up pandas.

```
2018-12-13 12:30:23,332] {bash_operator.py:87} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmppkovwfth/pscript_pclean_zjg4qfamp9pda9jsxysyrqfj_AWFtK5ucowyw2
[2018-12-13 12:30:23,333] {bash_operator.py:97} INFO - Running command: python /usr/local/airflow/rootfs/mopng_baseline_v2/scripts/pclean_zjg4qfamp9pda9jsxysyrqfj_AWFtK.py /usr/local/airflow/rootfs/mopng_baseline_v2/scheduled__2018-12-12T14:00:00+00:00/appended/DsDnV0TjSHnL0DF53JLjmUtO.csv /usr/local/airflow/rootfs/mopng_baseline_v2/scheduled__2018-12-12T14:00:00+00:00/pcleaned/ztYVV9nkh5t425gYjFqKuAD9.csv
[2018-12-13 12:30:23,344] {bash_operator.py:106} INFO - Output:
[2018-12-13 12:30:23,359] {bash_operator.py:110} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018-12-13 12:30:23,359] {bash_operator.py:110} INFO -   File "/usr/local/airflow/rootfs/mopng_baseline_v2/scripts/pclean_zjg4qfamp9pda9jsxysyrqfj_AWFtK.py", line 3, in <module>
[2018-12-13 12:30:23,359] {bash_operator.py:110} INFO -     import pandas as pd
[2018-12-13 12:30:23,360] {bash_operator.py:110} INFO - ImportError: No module named pandas
[2018-12-13 12:30:23,362] {bash_operator.py:114} INFO - Command exited with return code 1
[2018-12-13 12:30:23,383] {models.py:1736} ERROR - Bash command failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1633, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 118, in execute
    raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed
```

Answer (score 1):

The Operator failing is not a `PythonOperator`, it's a `BashOperator`. The most likely reason is that `python` in Bash is currently pointing to a different Python environment from the one running Airflow.

Be sure to specify `python3` in your `BashOperator`, or whatever extra configuration you need to invoke Python from the command line in the same environment as your `PythonOperator` does.

Comment: I changed the cmd command to use `python3` in the python file executing this command. However, no changes are reflected when I pushed the code to kubernetes cluster using docker. 
I used --no-cache while building the docker image. Should I also kill the pods?

Comment: I've never used Airflow on k8s but I'd guess so. If in doubt, recreate the cluster to test with a blank slate.